# Vagrant not showing any available network interfaces

Tags: vagrant

I have been running vagrant for the last month for a rails application with no problems on a home wirless network. I am running vagrant 1.4.3 and virtualbox on a windows machine..I have switched from the wireless i was using in old house to an new connection using a dongle (prepay plug and play internet USB device as I have moved) and am getting the following error..

```
 Bringing virtual machine 'default' up with 'virtual-box' provider..
 [default] clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
 [default] clearing any previously set network interfaces...
 [default] Available bridged network interfaces:
 [default] what interface should the network bridge to?
```

The problem is, when it is asking me "what interface should the network bridge to?", I am not being given any options as in the above.. Is there a particular file that can be edited to resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

Haven't tested this because my work computer refuses to run Vagrant properly, but it may be of some help to you.

Open up a command window in Windows and run "ipconfig /ALL", this will show all the network adapters on your computer and the output will probably look something like this (removed any identifying info):

```
Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Something
Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : something.something.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Peer-Peer
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : something.something.com

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : something.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Check Point Virtual Network Adapter For Endpoint VPN Client
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : AA-AA-AA-AA-AA-AA
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : something.something.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : AA-AA-AA-AA-AA-AA
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : aaaa::aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaaaaa(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 1.1.1.1(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 1.1.1.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 27. januar 2014 10:09:22
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 28. januar 2014 10:09:21
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 1.1.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 1.1.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 388265731
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-aa
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 1.1.1.1
                                       1.1.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-aa
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

See if you can find the name of your USB dongle in the list. Found it? If yes then try adding it to your Vagrantfile.

If I wanted to use my wireless adapter for networking, then according to the docs (http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/public_network.html) I would have to add this line to my Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network "public_network", :bridge => 'Wireless Network Connection'
```

Comment: Thanks for that..
I have found my dongle using ipconfig:

PPP adapter Broadband to Go:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : 
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : AA-AA-AA-AA-AA-AA
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : no
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
  aaaa::aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaaaaa(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 1.1.1.1(Preferred) 
 and have edited the vagrantfile as follows:

  config.vm.network "public_network", :bridge => 'PPP adapter Broadband to Go'

not sure if this is right as still not working getting same

Comment: It may have been the wrong way to specify the network name, navigate to the virtualbox install folder and run "VBoxManage.exe list bridgedifs" and see what it outputs.

Comment: Just did that and can't see adapter I'm looking for.. I've just noticed the DCHP is disabled in my dongle network adapter settings when running ipconfig. Do you think this may be the problem.. I've checked my settings in TCP/ip for this and have it set to 'obtain an IP address atuomatically' but still shows up as DHCP Enabled: No.

Comment: Can't say I know that much about the internal workings of virtualbox, but if the USB dongle shows up in network connections in Windows, can you try to click on it and the wired or wireless connection and bridge them?

Comment: I found out the type of usb isn't compatible for what I'm trying to do.. Many thanks for your help Kbrnsr.

Answer (score 1):

I've met this problem too.

> No available bridged network interfaces displayed

Today I solved it and here is what I have done:

- If you are using virtual box, find if there is a valid option displayed at the field called `name` in the [network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZYEY.png).
- If there is no valid option, Maybe your Virtualbox bridge network driver has been destroyed or something bad happened.
- Try to reinstall it just as [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnJO2.png). The path usually is `{VirtualBox}\drivers\network\netflt`.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the very same problem and I found out that it was because, *in my case* at least, the host was itself a virtual machine hosted on AWS. The adapters weren't detected by... Vagrant for a Bridged Network. I default to 'private_network' in the Vagrantfile.

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

I had it work and this solution was fit for the work I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently with windows 10 64 bits, and heard that would be because of some known bug or something.

I kept trying, and did the same as doraJam/Dale suggested above, and it was successful.

Basically, I removed my old version 6.0.4, and re-installed a new released version 6.0.6, and made sure the drivers for bridged network was selected on the wizard installation screen, restarted the machine, and then, just destroyed my old vagrant image "ubuntu/bionic64" in my case, and "vagrant up" again, and finally success, it was able to configure the image and loaded as expected.

I hope this work for those who facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem, in my opinion this is not Vagrant fault, its somethings related to the provider (in my case is Virtual Box). I solved my problem by installing the extension pack from Virtual Box official website. Restart the machine then my options show up in Vagrant.